# What public IP should I use for long-term network test?

Tags: networking, ping, ip-address

What IP address is OK to `ping -f` for a prolonged time (the whole day)? "4.2.2.2" or something else?

The main concern is the admins there that may decide that it is some DoS and block/complain...

Maybe there is special dedicated public test server somewhere that sends ICMP replies (including fast enough), runs TCP and UDP echo servers and other tools?..

Comment: One you own and whose CPU and network usage you pay for? Ping is probably the wrong tool for monitoring connectivity outages.

Comment: (My own cheap VPS is a bit unreliable). What is the good tool to catch short transient network outages (not needing a special server or that have pulic servers)?

Comment: Imho icmp can be a good tool to test network outages. Normal internet-usage like surfing only creates a problem when you have several packet-losts.

Comment: My ADSL router logs shows DSL disconnections and re-connections. Server syslog entries may show symptoms of connection failures for various services.

Comment: @Riscie: `man ping`: "This  program  is  intended for use in network testing, measurement and management.  Because of the load it can impose on the  network,  it  is  unwise  to use ping during normal operations or from automated scripts."

Comment: To monitor packet loss that does not actually cause users an observable problem you can keep an eye on `netstat -s | grep retransmited`

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick He is asking for an ip to ping for several days. I can only say, i've used ping on `8.8.8.8` for that purpose and it was no problem. You are right, there are beter tools and other options he has, but this is an easy one and i can confirm it works.

Comment: @Riscie: Sure but do bear in mind "[Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide.](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/)"

Comment: Ping **-f** ? Flood ping? I would say none. If someone did that to one of my servers I would consider it denial of service and complain to their provider.  One ping per second or something similar is something else. 100 pings per second (on modern systems) or as fast as your network pipe and will allow (older linux flood ping) it is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I've editet my answer because i did overread the `-f` parameter. Imho `-t` should not be a problem on google's dns server. They know how to disable icmp answers too ;)

Comment: I usually use `-f` with `-i`. Actually the script will do `while true; do if ping -w 1 -c 1 .....; then...else...fi; sleep 0.2; done`. It if there is an address to flood-ping without causing any problems if would be good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:
**As pointed out by RedGrittyBrick  and Hennes: `ping -f` is not a good idea on any public ip!**

*ping -t instead should imho not be a problem as this does not generate much network load.*

I always use Google's DNS-Server-Adresses:

```
8.8.8.8
```

or

```
8.8.4.4
```

and never encountered any problems with packet-losts etc.

Comment: I use this and 4.2.2.2 for pings, but I'm not sure about more prolonged and/or high-bandwidth tests. Is it really OK?

Comment: I had one test running for 5 days with no problems on 8.8.8.8.
Note sure what to say about high-bandwidth tests but icmp shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: I always use Google DNS as well.

Comment: Should I consider, for example, `ping -f -i 0.2` low-bandwidth enough for this?

Comment: Just use 

    `ping -t 8.8.8.8`

Don't concern about the bandwidth, no one will shut your connection down!

Comment: Where -t stands for timespan (eg ping 8.8.8.8 -t 120 would ping for 120 seconds. Leaving the time off implies a continuous ping)

Answer (score 2):

While I want to stress that leeching on someone else's service like this in a *permanent setup* is against my personal ethics, I will supply this pointer.

ICMP is often filtered or limited in rate of requests per source address, but HTTP services generally are not. You could use `nping` from [nmap](http://nmap.org/) which (by default) uses TCP handshakes on port 80 rather than ICMP echoes to detect connectivity. As a bonus it works without being root on UNIX systems. [The man page](http://nmap.org/book/nping-man.html) describes many, many options for it.

You'll have to either find a static address to a web server with good uptime (I have no idea how to tell if Google changes their front-end addresses) or rely on both a dns server AND a webserver. That might be an issue for your setup.

Comment: Replying to HTTP request is even more load than just replying the ICMP. And [semi-]flooded HTTP requests seem even more DoS'sy that flooded ICMPs. (Semi-flooded here means 4-40 requests per second).

Comment: nping opens a TCP connection, but doesn't issue an HTTP request.